# Can't connect to RabbitMQ by WebSocket via TLS

Tags: ssl, websocket, openssl, rabbitmq, web-stomp

Have made:

1. Setuped TLS support https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ssl
2. Configured Web-stomp plugin https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/web-stomp
3. RabbitMQ launched successfully ( rabbit_web_stomp: listening for HTTPS connections on 0.0.0.0:15673 )

Front-end use Stomp Over WebSocket ( http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/ )

OpenSSL connections failed with:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:15673 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000006)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 194 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1710675968
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```